# How to capture Camera's AV output to a Computer?

Tags: video

Could USB capture card afford 1080i capture?

I'm a Mac user, is there any AV output to FireWire converter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depends on the camera, and the OS. Lots of firewire equipped cameras will dump video straight to windows without any additional hardware required.

Answer (score 0):

[Elgato](http://www.elgato.com/) has devices and accompanying sofware for doing this kind of conversions (AV to USB, then to iTunes, iMovie and YouTube).